How to set a constant height and width (\textwidth) for the tikzpicture environment
I would like to set the width of my tikzpicture to exactly match \textwidth (no scale please).
My goal is to set a constant height and width (\textwidth) for the tikzpicture environment. Then, within this domain, I want to do my drawings.
CODE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[2]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,background rectangle/.style={double,ultra thick,draw=red, top color=blue, rounded corners}]
        
        \draw (0,0)--(10,10);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

OUTPUT:


And "no scale please" means you want to set x=<value> and y=<value>?

In principle you could try x=\dimexpr\textwidth/10\relax, y=\dimexpr\textwidth/10\relax, but that doesn't take into account the background rectangle.

May I ask what the end goal of all this is? (I could imagine that there is something with tcolorbox.) For pure TikZ images you will probably have to adjust the x and y scale on a case-by-case basis.

Hello all, my goal is to set a constant height and width (\textwidth). Then, within this constant domain, I want to draw my TikZ pictures.

tikzscale is about this

Add \path (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth-13pt,15cm); to your tikzpicture and keep your drawing within this space?

If you compile your drawing separately with class standalone and include it via graphicx in your main document, you'll have more degrees of freedom. See e.g. here for an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721930/245790 .
